# Form action value not updating - Javascript & React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I am attempting to set my forms action value to correspond with the value in a text field. The value does not get updated on text change like I expected. The value instead returns "https://URL/?image_link=undefined". Any ideas as to what is causing this?

```
import useForm from "./UseForm";

const FORM_ENDPOINT = "https://URL/?image_link="; // TODO - update to the correct endpoint
var final_endpoint=""
const Form = () => {
  const additionalData = {
    sent: new Date().toISOString(),
  };

  const { handleSubmit, status, message } = useForm({
    additionalData,
  });

  if (status === "success") {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="text-2xl">Thank you!</div>
        <div className="text-md">{message}</div>
      </>
    );
  }

  if (status === "error") {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="text-2xl">Something bad happened!</div>
        <div className="text-md">{message}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <form
      action={final_endpoint}
      id="myform"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      method="POST"
    >
      <div className="pt-0 mb-3">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Image Link"
          name="image_link"
          change={final_endpoint=FORM_ENDPOINT+document.getElementsByName('image_link').value}
          className="focus:outline-none focus:ring relative w-full px-3 py-3 text-sm text-gray-600 placeholder-gray-400 bg-white border-0 rounded shadow outline-none"
          required
        />
      </div>
      {status !== "loading" && (
        <div className="pt-0 mb-3">
          <button
            className="active:bg-blue-600 hover:shadow-lg focus:outline-none px-6 py-3 mb-1 mr-1 text-sm font-bold text-white uppercase transition-all duration-150 ease-linear bg-blue-500 rounded shadow outline-none"
            type="submit"
          >
            Submit Image
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

I have tried a few different ways of getting this working but am still unable too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried removing `method="POST"`? In React we don't necessarily need that like traditional HTML forms.